# Is it possible to link button to go to another page and open modal on it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if it was possible to link a button to a modal on another page, so basically when you click a button, another page loads (in new tab with target 0) and with modal opened on that page?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible.

Comment: How would one go about doing that, regarding the href attribute?

Comment: You would need to create a method of sending a message to the next page in order to open the modal when that page next loads. To do that you could use localStorage, sessionStorage, a cookie, the querystring, or even a serverside flag although it would be overkill. If you want specific help with this, please add the code you've written to the question so we can help you debug it. Remember that SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example of doing that using jQuery:

On the page with the button you need a normal link and an attribute `data-modal="modal-id"` with the id of your modal.

```
page1.html:

    <a class="open-modal" href="page2.html" data-modal="modal-ipsum" target="_blank">
      <button>Open Modal</button>
    </a>
```

On the page which opens when you click the button, you need the modal with the same id you set before in the `data-modal` attribute:

```
page2.html:

    <div class="modal" id="modal-ipsum">
      <h2>This is Modal Ipsum</h2>
    </div>
```

Then in your JS file:

```
main.js:

    $(".open-modal").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var modal = $(this).data("modal");
      var page = $(this).attr("href");

      localStorage.setItem('modal', modal);

      window.location.href = page;
    });

    if ("modal" in localStorage) {
      var modal = localStorage.getItem('modal');

      $("#" + modal).fadeIn();
    }
```

What that does is when you click a link with class `open-modal` it sets a key with the value `modal-ipsum` in your localStorage and then goes to the linked page.

On your 2nd page, you need to have the JS file linked aswell. When the document is ready, it checks if the localStorage contains an item called `modal`. If that's the case, it fades in the modal with the id `#modal-ipsum`.

*code is not tested*

This is just some help to get you started. Next time try something out and then ask for help on SO with your code, so we can help you more specifically.